FATAL EXCEPTION: main. Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
I tried to run my Android app but it has came up with errors in the process:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7765)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7276)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6983)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~NPJCyxcr9HPDLI7QxtcVOA==/com.example.a91p-PZS2_8JN6fx3PDG5K6iRag==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~NPJCyxcr9HPDLI7QxtcVOA==/com.example.a91p-PZS2_8JN6fx3PDG5K6iRag==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:2) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7765) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7276) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6983) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 

I have tried many solutions including installing google firebase plugins but gave me duplicate errors and have tried to change the versions of the google play services plugins to the same as each other but didn't work either. Are there any more solutions that I can try?
Here is my build.gradle.kts(project: appname)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.1")
    }
}

Here is my build.gradle.kts(module: app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.a91p"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.a91p"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
    implementation(libs.play.services)
    implementation("com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.4.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.2.0")
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0")
    implementation ("com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3")
}


This type of error accours when there is an issue with Google Play services or the Google Mobile Services (GMS) libraries integration in your app. Try Updating dependencies, clean and rebuild,
